# Checking SQL MAX() Function returning null

Tags: sql-server, null, max, sqldatareader

My problem is if my table is empty or the column on which I am using max function does not have the value I have specified, then why is sqlDataReader.hasRows TRUE?

It is giving a null record...how do I solve this problem??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a row. It's a row containing a column with the `NULL`. That's why `hasRows` returns `true`. Don't confuse the situation of "no rows are returned" with "a row has been returned, it contains `NULL`s"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An aggregate function like MAX() will always return one row per group. In your case, your group is the whole table. Therefore you get a one row resultset with the MAX value. Since you don't have data in your table, the MAX value is undefined, therefore NULL.

For better understanding try to replace MAX with COUNT. This will also return one row but with value 0. I think this is more intuitive and will help you better to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Make your query into a derived table and filter out `null` values in the main query.

```
select T.MaxValue
from (
     -- Your query goes here
     select max(Value) as MaxValue
     from YourTable
     where SomeCol > 10
     ) as T
where T.MaxValue is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, use the HAVING clause because HAVING can be used with aggregate functions:

```
select max(Value) from YourTable where SomeCol > 10
HAVING max(Value) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

> select top(select COUNT(*) from tbl) max(field) from tbl