# Getting empty answer when I should get nothing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a C# program that uses a SQL Server Compact database. I have a query where I want to select the highest number in a specific field that looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(nr2) FROM TABLE WHERE nr1 = '10'
```

This works as inteneded when there is a row where nr1 is 10. But I would expect to not get an answer when that row doesn't exist, but instead I get an empty field. So in my C# code I have:

```
text = result[0].ToString();
```

When I get a value from my SQL query the string contains a number and when the specified row doesn't exist I get an empty string.

This isn't really a big problem but I would be able to do the following check:

```
if (result.Count > 0)
```

Instead of:

```
if (result[0].ToString() == "")
```

which I have to do at the moment since count is always larger than 0.

Comment: What exactly does result[0] contain in this case? Is it a nullable datatype which contains NULL if the query doesn't return a result?

Comment: what you really want?

Comment: @KhurramAli I would like result.Count to be 0. I have another query that attempts to select a field from a table based on a condition and that returns result.Count = 0 sometimes when the condition insn't found in the table.

Comment: Please show more of the context (eg. how you are iterating over the query's result set): I have a strong suspision you problem is with how you are iterating.

Comment: @Richard It works on other querys where the condition I specify isn't found. Then I get result.Count = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk about using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but...

I don't test it with C# code, but in SQL Server Management Studio, if you run...

```
SELECT MAX(nr2) FROM TABLE WHERE nr1 = '10' HAVING MAX(nr2) IS NOT NULL
```

, the result is an empty collection, not a collection with one null (or empty) element.

NOTE: My answer is based on this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266570/982431). It seems that `MAX` and `COUNT` SQL functions returns always a single row collection.

Comment: I tested this but it always seem to return an empty collection, even when the specified value exists in the table

Comment: @JesperEvertsson sorry. Updated SQL statement! (And now I think it works...)

Comment: After the update I get an SqlCeException saying "There was an error parsing the query"

Comment: Sorry @JesperEvertsson, I didn't know that `IsNull` function does not available for SQL CE. I updated my answer with a new `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @HourSwords just a quick question to make sure I understand. Does HAVING work like WHERE but for functions?

Comment: @JesperEvertsson Yes, but not for functions: For aggregates. Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180199.aspx) to get more information.

Answer (score 2):

That SQL statement will always return a result... if the base query returns no result then the value of max() is null !

if you are using ADO.NEt, you could use ExecuteScalar, here an example :

```
private int GetIDNum()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(nr2) FROM TABLE WHERE nr1 = '10'", connection))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            object result = command.ExecuteScalar();

            if( result != null && result != DBNull.Value )
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32( result );
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using SQLCeDataReader but I guess I can do something similar

Comment: I guess so... Just check if ExecuteScalar is available... EXecuteScalar returns the value of the first field of the first row... In this case it will always be available !

Comment: Does it also work for mulitple rows? Beacuse the function i wrote to collect results is pretty general so I can use it for multiple purposes, including answers that has several rows.

Comment: Select MAX(*) from Table... Never returns multiple rows... ExecuteScalar is used only for that type of commands. It only returns the first field of the first row. 

For any other scenario, use a reader :=)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to be able to use the same function regarding of expecting just one row as an answer or 200.

Comment: Which function ? I give an example on how to use ExecuteScalar... do whatever you want with ... And if you only want one function for all your reads than you can not use it, and you just have to go through the normal SQLDataReader:=)

Comment: The function I wrote which my program uses every time it wants to make a select query. And I didn't mean to dissregard your answer, I just wanted to explain why I'm not using ExecuteScalar. Anyway, thanks for your help. Your answer solved the problem, but I prefered another answer a bit more